# ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item in multiple options select

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a multiple option select and everytime i submit the page i get:

ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "clients1" in application

```
for day in {something}

htp.p('<select class="custom-select" name="clients'||to_char(day+1)||'" id="clients'||to_char(day+1)||'" multiple>
<option selected>Open this select menu</option>');

for client in (SELECT id, name FROM    client) loop
   htp.p('<option value="'|| client.id ||'">'|| client.name ||'</option>');
end loop;

htp.p('</select></div></div></div>');
```

Looks like this :

```
<select class="custom-select" name="clients1" id="clients1" multiple=""><option selected="">Open this select menu</option>
<option value="1">Test</option>
...
</select>
```

I really can't find the problem. Tried to search for an answer but could not find anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APEX assumes that a form element such as a select list is an APEX page item if its name and id are the same, which yours are. So you can avoid this problem by making the names different from the IDs in some way.

The usual way to create bespoke form elements on an APEX page is to use the [APEX_ITEM](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEAPI/APEX_ITEM.htm#AEAPI192) package, which has functions like [SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEAPI/SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY-Function.htm#AEAPI208) to generate form elements whose values can be accessed from PL/SQL after page submit via [APEX_APPLICATION arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEAPI/Referencing-Arrays.htm#AEAPI215).